# Visual Studio / IIS: Dutch exceptions unsatisfactory

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis, non-english

In Visual Studio and IIS I get Dutch exceptions. I'd like them to be English in order to copy them to seek for a proper solution.

**I've tried:**

- Checking if I have any language pack installed
- (UI) culture in web.config
- Set Windows 8.1 to English primary language
- Set culture right before exception or in page itself

None of the options above help and I've checked the other questions on SO about this case (which describe the options above for example)
I'm in the dark about the proper solution and I hope there's just a setting instead of having to put something in every application.

Help appreciated.

**My setup:**

- Visual Studio 2012
- ReSharper 7
- IIS Express / Visual Studio Development Server

Comment: Is it an originally Dutch system?

Comment: Yes, but I'm willing to put it in English somehow to get rid of Dutch messages as they're worthless. Please don't tell me I have to do a clean install in English.

Comment: Not an answer, but can help to find the original english message : http://unlocalize.com/

Comment: @X.L.Ant I've seen that, but that's a work-around instead of an answer indeed. Thanks for the thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

The reason I guess is that the original machine was installed with the Dutch language pack. The IIS account is Dutch. You can set the current `Thread`s culture in .NET, but I don't know if it that smart to do that.

Options:

- Set the IIS language in `Home > .NET globalization`;
- Set the [`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (should do the same as you already did in the `web.config`);
- Reinstall to make it an English system;
- Change the user of IIS and set it to an account where you set the language to English.

Comment: I've stated IIS 7 in the question, but it's either Visual Studio Development Server or IIS Express. Can I change it there somehow?

Comment: Maybe in the config files, but I am not sure. Those application are totally different than IIS and how IIS works...